# How do I save this Java POJO in for loop into a Repository?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to loop over Java POJO creation but intellij is giving errors.

```
Company c1 = new Company("Company_Name_1");
Company c2 = new Company("Company_Name_2");
Company c3 = new Company("Company_Name_3");

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {
    try {
        companyRepository.save("c" + i); // this!
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
companyRepository.save("c" + String.valueOf(i));   // error

companyRepository.save("c" + Integer.getInteger(i)); // error
```

Error says Inferred Type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within bounds.

Any ideas on fixing this error?

Comment: You can't dynamically name variables in java. The string "c1" can't be made into a variable name. Use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3).forEach(c -> {
    try {
        companyRepository.save(c);
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
})
```